# How to left/right align lines in rich edit (Delphi)?

Tags: delphi, richedit

Is there a way I can align the line left or right in the `TRichEdit` component?

#### Clarification

I wish to align only a portion of the text, not all of it.

Comment: Yes, use the "paragraph".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sertac mentioned in a comment, you use the `TRichEdit.Paragraph.Alignment`.

```
RichEdit1.Paragraph.Alignment := taLeftJustify;
RichEdit1.Lines.Add('This line is left justified.');
RichEdit1.Paragraph.Alignment := taCenterJustify;
RichEdit1.Lines.Add('This line is centered.');
RichEdit1.Paragraph.Alignment := taRightJustify;
RichEdit1.Lines.Add('This line is right justified');
```